# Adding constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, xcode, oracle

I would like to add constraint:Address must be more than 6 characters long, to the attribute ADDRESS_STREET. I tried LENGTH(address_street)>6 it is failed.

I would also like to add constraint: Date after 01/01/2001 to attribute SERVICE_DATE. I tried CHECK("SERVICE_DATE" > ‘01/01/2000’), which is also failed. What should I do if I would like to add the constraint?

Answer (score 1):

These should be phrased as:

```
alter t add constraint chk_t_address_street check (length(address_street) > 6));

alter t add constraint chk_t_service_date check (service_date > date '2000-01-01');
```

Note that these constraints will still allow `NULL` values.  To prevent that, declare the columns `NOT NULL`.

Comment: length(address) > 6 Is the address inside () the attribute name? Should it be address_street?